# Way to check if user is scrolling?

Tags: android

I have a scrollview in my layout and I want to be able to check if the user is scrolling. I checked the  [Scrollview in Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html), but I don't see anything like isScrolling() that returns a boolean.

My question is: is there a way to check if the user is attempting to scroll, as opposed to clicking a button?  Could there be some other class in the Android core that is monitoring the scroll event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a better way but here is how you can figure it out.

You get a MotionEvent object inside the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` method.
check the action of the motion event as `ev.getAction()`.

If the action is ACTION_MOVE it implies that a scrolling is taking place.

Note: Scrolling is different than a fling. So the same logic cannot be used to determine if the fling is over.